# Autowiring of exchange, queue and binding with Spring AMQP + RabbitMQ (Spring Boot)

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-boot, spring-amqp

In the Spring docs for [Messaging with RabbitMQ](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/), `rabbitTemplate`, `queue`, `exchange` and `binding` are all set up by Spring Boot. What I don't understand is how `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(...)` sends it to the created exchange, since the method call does not specify an exchange and it includes only the routing key (via the queue name) and the message itself - which I thought implicitly sends the message to the default exchange and not the created exchange. The message will reach the intended queue since the routing key matches the name of the queue.

If I wanted to specify the exchange and routing key, using this API method:

```java
// Convert a Java object to an Amqp Message and send it to
// a specific exchange with a specific routing key.
convertAndSend(String exchange, String routingKey, Object object);
```

... how do I get a reference to the *created* `exchange`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot's `RabbitAutoConfiguration` only registers the connection factory, a `RabbitAdmin` a `RabbitTemplate` and a `RabbitMessagingTemplate`.

That guide declares its own exchange, queue, and binding.

You can simply `@Autowire` the exchange as normal and call `getName()`.

Comment: I am grappling with Spring Boot a bit, being really new to it. I want to avoid XML configuration, so how do I `@Autowire` an exchange? Will simply declaring a `@Autowired` TopicExchange exchange;` create one and wire it, or do I need to create one explicitly via Java configuration? Some example code would be tremendously useful, if it is not too much to ask. Thanks!

Comment: That guide you cited declares a `@Bean TopicExchange exchange()` (no xml); that defines the bean. You then can simply auto wire a bean with that name into your app to access its name just like you autowired your rabbit template.

Comment: I was able to do just that. Simply added an `@Autowired DirectExchange exchange;` and was able to access the `Exchange` instance. Thanks!

Comment: How do I override the virtual host, host, user name and password properties when using Boot's `RabbitAutoConfiguration`?

Comment: Just add properties; scroll down to the available rabbit properties in [the appendix](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).